# Calculate image transformations from original and resultant projected image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, transform

I have an image ('Original Image', top) which is projected and transformed (e.g. scaled,  rotated, mirrored), then captured by a camera ('Captured Image', bottom). How can I tell what transformations have taken place - eg. scaling in x and/or y, horizontal/vertical mirroring, rotation.

I do not require an entirely automated solution. The user can identify unique features from the Original Image and the corresponding Captured Image.

In the examples below, the Captured Image is 1) Mirrored Horizontally, Rotated about -2.3 degrees, stretched horizontally to about 150%, compressed vertically to about 80%.

[image: Original Image]

[image: Captured Image]

I hope the blurriness is not too much of a problem - it is not important for the quesion (i.e. I don't want to try and resolve the degree of blur in the captured image).

Comment: for some mathmatical background look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77462/finding-transformation-matrix-between-two-2d-coordinate-frames-pixel-plane-to-w and here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you @JulianS. for those links. A little beyond my maths, but I will get there!